# Live tile image not updating on time

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

So in short, my issue is that the background image for my Live Tile is not being updated.

I know that the correct image is in Isolated Storage, and I also know that it is being set as the image for the tile, however only the tile sizes not currently being viewed update. For the tile size currently being used to update, the user has to cycle through the tile sizes several times. I assume the issue is something to do with a tile cache being constructed, and not easily being cleared. However, I have tried a few different methods to clear it - clearing all properties on the tile, setting unique filenames for each icon, and none have worked - I'm still forced to either cycle through the tiles or unpin and repin for the icon to update.

Are there any solutions or workarounds for this to force an update?

EDIT: The code I am using is:

```
Canvas canvasIcon = DrawCanvas(100, 172, 30, 30, brushWhite, brushWhite, PenLineCap.Square, 10);
WriteableBitmap wbIcon = new WriteableBitmap(canvasIcon, null);
wbIcon.Invalidate();

var stream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("Shared/ShellContent/icon.png", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, isoStore);
wbIcon.WritePNG(stream);
stream.Close();

IconicTileData iconicTile = new IconicTileData() {
    SmallIconImage = new Uri("isostore:/Shared/ShellContent/smallicon.png", UriKind.Absolute),
    Title = "Placeholder",
    IconImage = new Uri("isostore:/Shared/ShellContent/icon.png", UriKind.Absolute)
};

ShellTile tile = ShellTile.ActiveTiles.First();
tile.Update(iconicTile);
```

Comment: Can you show a way to reproduce the issue you are seeing.

Comment: Can you post your code where you initialize the tile?

Comment: This example works for me, try this in your code

http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Live_Tile_Templates_in_Windows_Phone_8

Comment: I am using the ToolStack PNG Library if that makes a difference (it does seem to be a lot slower than SaveJPEG although I haven't actually done a formal test), but like I said, I've checked the Isolated Storage using Power Tools, and the correct image is definitely there, and if I unpin and then re-pin the tile the image updates immediately without me entering the application

Comment: @ChristopherCabezudoRodriguez , I imagine that would be an excellent solution for secondary tiles, however an app's primary tile cannot be created or deleted through the app, and hence unfortunately I can't force a refresh that way

Comment: Ho i miss that point, let me keep researching.